# Determine if a URL will redirect the client to some other URL, using only the URL string

Tags: http, url, http-redirect, redirect

Can I rely on the following statement?

A URL will redirect the client to some other URL **if and only if** it contains more than a single occurrence of "http://" and/or "https://"?

Note: by 'and/or' I mean that a single occurrence of each token is still counted as two occurrences.

I am guessing that the answer is no, because some URLs with only a single such token may still lead the client to a web-page that will then run some javascript, which will eventually redirect the client.

If the answer is indeed no, then is there any other way for me to determine that without "going into the URL" (with a URL-Connection, a browser, Selenium, etc)?

Thanks

Comment: No. You would have to go to the URL.

Comment: You will have to fetch the page to see where it will redirect you. But you don't need a web browser for it. A simple `netcat` or `curl` will show if the returned page is a 301, 302, 303, or any 3XX. Here is a sample output when you issue `curl http://google.com`.
 `<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>`

Comment: And how do I "curl" in Java?

Comment: @barakmanos To check response code while using an `HttpUrlConnection` you can call `getResponseCode()` method on its object. It returns an integer code. example: 200-for OK, 301-for permanent redirection etc.

Comment: @boxed__l, thanks, but this doesn't work in 100% of all cases. Method 'getResponseCode' may return 200, while the URL will still redirect a client to somewhere else. So neither HttpURLConnection nor "curl" (which are equivalent I guess) provide a "full-proof" solution (though, I will be glad to hear any usage suggestion that proves otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to know from the URL whether you will be redirected or not. For example, http://bit.ly/1dprzK4 redirects here- without any additional "http://" or "https://".

There is nothing in an URL that says you will or won't be redirected. Redirecting or not is the choice of the web server / application no matter what the URL looks like.

Comment: Short and accurate answer; thanks. BTW, how were you able to generate that URL which redirects to this page?

Comment: @barakmanos - go to http://bit.ly then paste this stackoverflow url and it will give you a new url which you can paste here like this http://bit.ly/1dprzK4.